# What is the obj?.prop syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I was looking through a code and I came across this:

```
{{abc?.xvy=== tyu?abc?.xz:abc?.xz}}
```

I am unable to understand meaning of this expression. I know that it is Null-safe property access but I am bit confused about the chaining.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I hope this code isn't used anywhere.

Comment: unfortunately I saw it is used. Why is it not supposed to be used ?

Comment: It really isn't readable at all, `abc`, `xvy` `tyu` are too generic to be useful and the ternay operator is useless because both outcomes are the same, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54528900/6419007)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its new ES proposal called "optionals" for safe check reading for object properties. Above expression is equivalent to:

```
(abc && abc.xvy) === (tyu) ? (abc && abc.xz) : (abc && abc.xz)
```

You can find more details here: https://github.com/davidyaha/ecmascript-optionals-proposal

Comment: OP's code doesn't have any standalone reference to an `xz` variable, though.

Comment: `(tyu) ? (abc && abc.xz) : (abc && abc.xz)` is just `abc && abc.xz`

Answer (score 8):

This looks to be an example of the [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) proposal, which is still very much a work in progress (only at Stage 1). It's not actually implemented in vanilla JS environments yet. Using

```
obj?.prop
```

means: if `obj` is undefined or null, the expression evaluates to `undefined`. But otherwise, it will evaluate to the `prop` property on the object. This is syntax sugar for

```
obj && obj.prop
```

(using just `obj.prop` alone will throw if `obj` is undefined or null)

So, your

```
abc?.xvy=== tyu?abc?.xz:abc?.xz
```

will evaluate to `true` if the nested value `abc?.xvy` is equal to the nested value `abc?.xz` - *or*, it will evaluate to `true` if at least one of the nested values doesn't exist, and the other is `undefined`.

Spaced out for easier reading:

```
abc?.xvy === tyu
? abc?.xz
: abc?.xz
```

As you can see, both `?` and `:` expressions are the same, making the conditional operator unnecessary here. An equivalent test (assuming that referencing `tyu` doesn't throw) would be

```
abc?.xvy === abc?.xz
```

Answer (score 5):

It's called **Null Propagation Operator**.

We can think of each **?.** operator as a short circuit where "*if the expression up until this point is **null** or **undefined**, then the whole expression evaluates to **undefined***".
We could also optionally call functions.