# What is the ?. operator and Where I can the use ?? Nullish Coalescing Operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I found this pieces of code: Here, What is the `?.` JavaScript operator? And Will I be able to use `??` Nullish Coalescing Operator in JavaScript instead of `||` OR operator according to the mentioned code snippet below?

```
const location = {
  lat: data?.coords?.latitude,
  long: data?.coords?.longitude
}
```

```
const docId = auth.currentUser?.uid || '123'
```

Comment: Technically you should be using `??` instead of `||`, as there is a chance `uid` may return a falsy value that is neither null nor undefined: `const docId = auth.currentUser?.uid ?? '123'`

Comment: @ViduminiKulathunga It's the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the obj?.prop syntax in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528778/what-is-the-obj-prop-syntax-in-javascript)

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking. This code:

```
const location = {
  lat: data?.coords?.latitude,
  long: data?.coords?.longitude
}
```

assigns `undefined` to `lat` if either `data` or `data.coords` is `null` or `undefined` (rather than throwing an error). But if `data` and `data.coords` are both *not* `null` or `undefined`, it assigns `data.coords.latitude` and `data.coords.longitude` to `lat` and `long`. It's the new [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator.

The next line also uses it, but:

1. If the `uid` could be a falsy value (like `""` or `0`), you should use the new [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator as well: `??` rather than `||`.
2. If `auth` may be `null` or `undefined`, you need another `?.`

So:

```
const docId = auth?.currentUser?.uid ?? '123'
```

Comment: That's neat, since when JS allows a *null-conditional* operator like in C# ? Is that new or have I missed this since a lot of time ?

Comment: @Cid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript